# Words or phrases to describe how street beggars typically look?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives, phrasing

I'm writing a scene in which I wish to describe a typical street beggar - his way of dressing in particular. Check for example such a dude as the one below

[image]

I could use descriptions such as: snobbish, dirty, bizarre, rugged, barbaric, etc but feel those are not adequate to building a picture of a beggar in the minds of my readers. I want words that would describe a sort of beggar that typically, you'd wish to avoid - one very pitiful, but also repugnant?

What words or phrases would you use for such a description?

Comment: That fellow is not a beggar, he's a busker. Could be the next Dylan.

Comment: I read "disheveled" in a lot of books.  But many times it's used to describe someone that usually isn't.  To describe what looks like a more permanent state of being, I'm not sure it would work.  I like wretched below best but thought I mention this one.

Comment: *snobbish* ????

Answer (score 1):

How about **ragamuffin**

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ragamuffin):

> A muffin is a poor thing of a creature, a 'regular muff'; so that a ragamuffin is a sorry creature in rags.

Another frequently used word is **bum** and also **vagabond** which usually refers to a person that doesn't have a settled house and travels from place to place

Answer (score 0):

Instead of derelict, or scum, or wretched.... How about a person who is less fortunate draped with the cloth of life's unfortunate spirals of which any of us could bare, at any particular time...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Destitute, Indigent, Needy** or such similar words in your play or written piece without losing meaning. You can also do Thesauri search online for **Destitute** and find other words to use in your play.

Comment: These terms all describe the person's economic status; the question was primarily concerned with the appearances.